# How to use socketio in azure web app for container

Tags: node.js, azure, socket.io, containers

I am using web for container in azure
- platform linux

My application was written in Node.js with socketio.
I use docker for create container.

I've already tested in local machince websocket is work fine but when I deploy to azure web for container.

When I try to connect websocket, I always got error code 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable.

Comment: Can you provide more details? The image you use and how do you test the image locally?

Comment: I just use docker run normally
- I try change to alternative to use azure container instance. it work with web-socket
- Next step I come back to azure app service again and change platform to window It show toggle button for websocket. But I have still not tried it yet...